# User routing Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-routing, laravel-5.4

I want my user to access its profile edit page by URL: `/profile/slug/edit`, where slug means `$user->slug`.
My `web.php` contans:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
Route::get('/profile/{slug}', [
'uses' => 'ProfilesController@index',
'as' => 'profile'
]);
Route::get('/profile/{slug}/edit', [
'uses' => 'ProfilesController@edit',
'as' => 'profile.edit'
]);
```

How to call `ProfilesController@edit` from view, how to pass parameters correctly? Tried:

```
<a href="{{route('profile', ['slug'=> Auth::user()->slug],'edit')}}">
Edit your profile</a>
```

Comment: Your route should have profile.edit instead of only profile. And remove profile as the third parameter of the route function.

Comment: Is it possible to simplify my code? And shorten my code? I foud prefix'es, but how to deal with 'slug', I have to pass it in my every `route()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it..

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/profile/{slug}', 'ProfilesController@index')->name('profile');
    Route::get('/profile/{slug}/edit', 'ProfilesController@edit')->name('profile.edit');
});
```

And then in your view, you can use..

```
<a href="{{ route('profile.edit', Auth::user()->slug) }}">Edit your profile</a>
```

As you can see, first we have to give the `route()` the route name we are interested in, in your case it's `profile.edit` that is the target route, and we know from our routes file that it's missing the **slug** value, so we provide it the slug value as the second argument (if there are more missing values, the second argument should be an array).

It takes some practice and time but try different ways to see what makes your code more readable. The number of lines doesn't matter that much to the computer, write the code so you can easily read and understand it if you want to change something a year or two from now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following codeline

```
<a href="{{ route('profile.edit', ['slug' => Auth::user()->slug]) }}"> Edit your profile</a>
```

Your routes definitions seems to be fine.

Plus if you want to add some get params, you can add directly in the array passed as the second argument

```
<a href="{{ route('profile.edit', ['slug' => Auth::user()->slug, 'otherparam' => 'value']) }}"> Edit your profile</a>
```

Hope this helps. :)